# Removing and returning the background in a form element on focus

Tags: jquery, css, forms

```
/* clears default text in a field on entry */
$('#edit-field-activity-notes-und-0-value')
    .each(function() {
        $(this).data('default', this.value);
       var mybackground = $(this).css('background'); **
    })
    .focusin(function() {
        if ( this.value == $(this).data('default') ) {
            this.value = '';    
            $(this).css( 'background', 'white');   
        }
    })
    .focusout(function() {
        if ( this.value == '' ) {
            this.value = $(this).data('default');
           this.css = $(this).css ('background', mybackground); **
        }
    });
```

What going on here? 
$(this).css( 'background', 'white'); works but leaves all the guff like no-repeat in place

This lines with the ** are total failures.

Comment: Use `background-color`. `background` is a shortcut and will reset all non-specified background properties (such as `backgroudn-repeat`, `background-image` etc) to their defaults.

Comment: var mybackground shoud not be reachable in focusout because of different scope.

Comment: This may not be the answer for your question but why don't you use css for this? You can just use :hover

Comment: @Nishan Senevirathna Focus is not hover event :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change this:

```
 this.css = $(this).css ('background', mybackground);
```

into:

```
 $(this).css ('background', mybackground);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `mybackground` variable is not in scope of the `focusout` function, and setting a variable to the return value of `$.css()` is redundant.

Also, you should set `background-color` as `background` is a shortcut and will reset all non-specified background properties (such as `background-repeat`, `background-image` etc) to their defaults. Try this:

```
var mybackground;
$('#edit-field-activity-notes-und-0-value').each(function() {
    $(this).data('default', this.value);
    mybackground = $(this).css('background');
})
.focusin(function() {
    if (this.value == $(this).data('default')) {
        this.value = '';    
        $(this).css('background-color', 'white');   
    }
})
.focusout(function() {
    if (this.value == '') {
        this.value = $(this).data('default');
        $(this).css('background-color', mybackground);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/* clears default text in a field on entry */
$('#edit-field-activity-notes-und-0-value')
    .each(function() {
        $(this).data('default', this.value);
    })
    .focusin(function() {
        if ( this.value == $(this).data('default') ) {
            this.value = '';    
            $(this).css('background', 'none');               
        }
    })
    .focusout(function() {
        if ( this.value == '' ) {
            this.value = $(this).data('default');  
            $('#edit-field-activity-notes-und-0-value').css('background', 'url(sites/all/themes/bartiksub/images/add-message.png) no-repeat center center');
            }else{
            $('#edit-field-activity-notes-und-0-value').css('background', 'url(sites/all/themes/bartiksub/images/add-message-after.png) no-repeat center center');
        }
    });
```

Think here is because it is written into the element and not the CSS file it requires the path to the image to be from the root of the site. (Drupal)

Hence when you add back what is saved in the var (the original idea) you would have to add back the missing part of the path.